# Serialized column in where clause Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I'm using a serialized column in my Product model as:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :price
   serialize :price
end
```

The price column is added as a text column as done for Serialized columns. The price attribute has further 2 attributes 'value' and 'currency' and in stored in Database as:

```
#<Product id: 1482, price: {:value=>"500", :currency=>"INR"}, created_at: "2013-05-30 14:35:17", updated_at: "2013-05-30 14:35:22">
```

Now I want to get the count of Products with price value greater than 200 bucks and so write the active record query as:

```
Product.where('price[:value] > ?', 200).count
```

but it gives me the error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[:value] is not null)' at line 1: SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`  WHERE (price[:value] is > 200)
```

I am finding no way to access serialized attributes in where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your column is serialized, it is ruby code inside it, which means you need Ruby to "filter" on this column. The important thing to know is that it **can take a while** for you app to do this instruction, depending on your products number in database.

```
Product.scoped.select{ |p| p.price[:value] > 200 }.count
```

`Product.scoped` is similar to `Product.all`.
You may need to turn `p.price[:value]` into an `int` (seems to be a String in DB).

Comment: The solution looks good. We can make this query faster by indexing the price column. If you have any other solution with better performance do update us.

Answer (score 0):

For getting particular key from json, you need to use [json_extract_path_text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html)(json_column, 'json_property') and then [LATERAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join to reference the extracted value:

If we need to write RAW SQL query, it would be something like this(assuming your `table` name is `products`):

```
SELECT *
  FROM products
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL json_extract_path_text(price, 'value') val ON TRUE
  WHERE val::integer > 200;
```

**Note**: `val::integer` is used because your schema contains value of `value` key as `string`

Now if we try to re-write this as an `ActiveRecord` query, it should look something like:

```
Product.joins("LEFT JOIN LATERAL json_extract_path_text(products.price, 'value') val ON TRUE").
where("val::integer > 200")
```